# how to get the queue in which a task was run - celery

Tags: python, queue, task, celery

I'm new using celery and have a question. I have this simple task:

```
@app.task(name='test_install_queue')
def test_install_queue():
    return subprocess.call("exit 0",shell=True)
```

and I am calling this task later in a test case like

```
result = tasks.test_default_queue.apply_async(queue="install")
```

The task run successfully in the queue `install` (because I am seeing it in the celery log, and it completes fine. But I would like to know a programmatically way of finding in which queue was the task `test_install_queue` run, from the object stored in `result`.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I've changed the tasks to be like:

```
@app.task(name='test_install_queue',bind=True)
def test_install_queue(self):
    return self.request.__dict__
```

and then I'm using the result of `apply_async` as follows:

```
result = tasks.test_install_queue.apply_async(queue="install")
assert "install" in result.get()["hostname"]
```

and the workaround is that the worker (hostname) has the same name as the only queue that is initialized in the worker.

Comment: This might help: [How can I get the task id of the current task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-get-the-task-id-of-the-current-task)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need the task ID, I need the queue in which the task ran. I read through the Celery documentation but I didn't find anything.

Comment: See the link referred in that section -> http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-request-info

Comment: And just FYI, if you don't specify a name for the task it will be the same as the function name, so in your example the task name is unnecessary. Also, you can specify the queue for each task instead of calling it if it's always in the same queue.

So it would be something like: `@app.task(queue='install')` instead.

Comment: Thank you both. The problem is not with the queue or routing, I want to try to get the queue name from the celery worker (I'm setting the queue statically in order to ensure that the queue that I will "programatically" get is the right one.

Comment: @fedorqui actually that was a workaround I've used, not does not give me the right thing. See edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
delivery_info = app.current_task.request.delivery_info
# by default celery uses the same name for queues and exchanges
original_queue = delivery_info['exchange']
for queue in app.amqp.queues.itervalues():
    if queue.exchange.name == delivery_info['exchange'] 
        and queue.routing_key == delivery_info['routing_key']:
            original_queue = queue.name
            break
```

That approach is built on assumption that you use default celery settings and your exchanges are direct. If you need more universal solution for fanout and topic exchanges then you will have to check routing keys of every declared queue in `app.amqp.queues`.

Comment: I was able to do a workaround at the end, but your answer is still valid. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I've just faced this issue myself and I was really sceptic about the need of a convoluted solution such the one from "lexabug" that has been accepted...
So, since even the Celery documentation does not provide an effective alternative, I've investigated by myself using reflection in order to understand which object contains the info I need and I came up with a super easy and straightforward solution. Specifically, I was writing an hook, or better, a signal in Celery terms, and this is how I retrieved the name of the queue based on the task name:

```
    @signals.after_task_publish.connect()
    def on_task_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):

        # "sender" is a string containing task name 
        # ("celery" here is the celery app)
        task: Task = celery.tasks.get(sender)

        # once we have the task object, we can access the "queue" property 
        # which contains the name of the queue 
        # (it' a dynamic property so don't expect support by your IDE)
        queue_name: str = task.queue if task is not None else 'unknown'
```

ps. I'm using Celery 4.4

Comment: "I was really sceptic about the need of a convoluted solution"

I also was very sceptical of this need, but honestly even after digging in the celery and kombu codebase for awhile, it's unclear to me why `delivery_info` is not present or why the `queue` and `exchange` etc values in the hook are null. Thanks for this, though.

Comment: Also, `after_task_publish` takes a `routing_key` kwarg that seems to match the name of the queue.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  For me, `task.queue` isn't the current task's current queue, it's the shared_task's hardcoded queue.  If you queue to a different place, or have eager on, etc, it's not the value you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the task is a [bound task](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks), you can get the name of the queue using `self.request.delivery_info['routing_key']`