# Celery: get the queue, from which the task has been received

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

Celery is configured to use AMQP (RabbitMQ used as broker).

I have a simple task that looks like this:

```
@shared_task
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    return "result"
```

How do I figure out from which **queue** the task has been received?

I know I can do something like this:

```
from celery import current_task
current_task.delivery_info
```

which gives the exchange and the routing key, but not the queue.

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: @georgexsh `"rpc://"` if it's relevant...

Comment: my mistake, when I say 'backend', I refer to broker transport, and, now I know that you're using amqp.

Comment: @georgexsh I adjusted the question to make it more explicit, thanks :)

Comment: See the following link, I beleive this solves your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385297/how-to-get-the-queue-in-which-a-task-was-run-celery